# Error on Installing Apache kafka python client

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I was trying to install Apache kafka python client on my mac, and when I was trying to run the unit tests:

> python -m test.unit

then throw up the error

/usr/bin/python: No module named test.unit

and I had followed the steps given in Github link: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/tree/0.7

Please help me what I can do?

Comment: and also I can not found the kafka-src folder on kafka-phython directory.

Comment: What steps did you use to install? I've successfully installed it with a simple 'pip install kafka-python', but I'm not on my mac right now. The pip installation does not install any unit tests that I can see, and you shouldn't need them if you just want to use the client.

Comment: I had used setup.py directly: clone code from github: > git clone https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python then gone to kafka-python folder
> cd kafka-python and installed through setup.py
> python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

kafka-python tests are run via `tox` . I typically do something like:

`KAFKA_VERSION=0.10.0.1 tox -e py27`

It looks to me like your github reference is very old (`tree/0.7` is extremely old). Go to https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python or http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/ for docs